# The naming of constants; Type or Name first?

Tags: java, variables, constants

Something that has bugged me for a long time is the naming of constants.

For example a path to saved images on disk:

```
PATH_IMAGES
```

And a url to saved images:

```
URL_IMAGES
```

But I can also use `IMAGES_PATH` and `IMAGES_URL`. The same applies for normal variable names:
`users_screen` or `screen_users` for a screen that displays a list of users.

Is there a standard for which part should come first?

Of course if possible type should not be included in the variable name. But there are many cases in which this isn't possible.

Comment: I think it's personal flavor, so the answers will be opinionated. But I think type first is more handy.

Comment: A personal choice I would say, no hard and fast rules to name them. Depends more on whom your writing the code for. I work in a startup where we have our own set of naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's obviously no hard and fast rule but the typical convention would be to use `[CATEGORY]_[ITEM]` because this is a neater and more easily-navigable way of managing things.

Consider something where you have several paths and several screens. You might have:

- PATH_ITEM
- PATH_ANOTHER_ITEM
- PATH_A_FINAL_ITEM
- SCREEN_USER
- SCREEN_ADMIN
- SCREEN_HOME

This is much easier to manage/read/navigate than:

- ITEM_PATH
- ANOTHER_ITEM_PATH
- A_FINAL_ITEM_PATH
- USER_SCREEN
- ADMIN_SCREEN
- HOME_SCREEN

Generally, with naming conventions, the best thing to do is start broad and end specific.

"Normal variable names" are a slightly different case as you typically want something that reads well in flowing code, rather than something that is in a well-organised hierarchy of items, e.g.:

```
String imagePath = myImage.path;
```

It's worth noting, also, that while Oracle provides [naming guidelines for constants](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), they aren't specific about what you're asking, so it will ultimately come down to opinion and readability. Honestly, as long as you are consistent, it doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: "Generally, with naming conventions, the best thing to do is start broad and end specific." Excellent! I suspect my problem was that i wasn't consistent and used both naming conventions in different projects, that caused the confusion and in the end the question. Thank you and Black and Time B for the extensive and clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just think what makes most sense in the larger scope of the program and how it is being used.

For example if you have multiple "images" constants then it would make sense to have them all start with `IMAGES` since then all you need to do is start typing `IMA` and then code completion will let you see the list of all constants related to images.

On the other hand if you usually start with thinking about paths and are looking for all possible paths most of the time it might make sense to group all the `PATH_` stuff together.

The key thing is to be consistent within your code - and ideally consistent with any libraries you are using a lot as well.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle prefers the DETAIL_TYPE in its naming, e.g.

- **CharSequence** as class name (instead of SequenceChar)
- java.lang.String.**CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER** instead of java.lang.String.ORDER_CASE_INSENSITIVE

Therefore, it would be **usersScreen** in Your example.

However, as general rule: Use the naming that supports readability.